# Select random 'eq' of div but different div each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I am selecting a random instance of a class.  I can repeat the same instance, but just not back to back. For example, I can select the `2nd instance, 3rd instance, 2nd instance` but not `2nd instance, 2nd instance, 3rd instance`  Here's my code:

```
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
DevRotator = {
        initialDev: '.featured-dev.initial',
        notInitial: '#loaded-devs .featured-dev',
        init: function() {
            setInterval(this.changeDevs.bind(this), 3000);
        },
        changeDevs: function() {

            var devToFlip = [Math.floor(Math.random()*$(this.initialDev).length)];

            $(this.initialDev).removeClass('animated flipInX');
        var randomInitial = $(this.initialDev).eq(devToFlip);
        randomInitial.addClass('animated flipInX');
        randomInitial.clone().appendTo("#loaded-devs").removeClass("initial animated flipInX");


            setTimeout(this.changeDevs, 3000);
        }
    }
```

This works great except sometimes it selects the same div, which messes up my animation.  How can I continue to select random divs, without making sure the same div doesn't repeat back-to-back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to *store* the last selected div is to add a class (or another attribute) to it. Here is a take which I think achieves the same result in a simpler way than the other answers:

```
changeDevs: function() {
    var divNotToFlip = $('div.lastOne');
    var candidateDivs = $('div:not(.lastOne)');
    var divToFlip = candidateDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*candidateDivs.length));
    divToFlip.addClass('animated flipInX lastOne');
    divNotToFlip.removeClass('lastOne animated flipInX');  //Return the last selected div to the pool
}
```

Note: I also removed the setTimeout function in changeDevs function. Using this method, there is no need for new fields in `DevRotator` object just to hold the last selected element.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj8awu2z/)

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last selected div...

```
 lastDiv: -1;
 changeDevs: function() {
     var devToFlip = 1; 
     while (devToFlip == this.lastDiv)
          {devToFlip = [Math.floor(Math.random()*$(this.notInitial).length))]};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this does not solve the issue.  I still have divs being repeated.  As a matter of fact, this simply selects the same div over and over.

Comment: I noticed the randomizer line in this answer has `this.notInitial` whereas the original had `this.initialDev`...

Comment: @JordanBarber sorry, more specifically the `Math.random()*$(this.initialDev).length` part, which doesn't seem to have changed in the question, looking back at the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the last found item in a variable, then the next time it gets a div, filters out that div from the list of divs, then selects a random div from the result of that.

This is the main part of it

```
// get a random index that's 1 less than the length of the initDev
// array because we'll be removing an item

var randomInitial = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($(this.initialDev).length - 1));

// get an array that does not include the one we previously used
// and select the item at randomInital
this.lastDiv = $(this.initialDev).filter(function() { return this != self.lastDiv; })[randomInitial];
```

See this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JWhite18/seqzqL10/1/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Stored the current value as `lastItem`, then generates new Random Value for `devToFlip` untill `devToFlip ! = lastItem`. After coming out of `while loop`, saves the newly generated `devToFlip` as `lastItem`.

```js
var DevRotator = {
  initialDev: '.featured-dev.initial',
  notInitial: '#loaded-devs .featured-dev',
  lastItem: null,
  devToFlip: null,
  init: function() {
    setInterval(this.changeDevs.bind(this), 100);
  },
  changeDevs: function() {
    this.lastItem = this.devToFlip;
    while (this.devToFlip == this.lastItem) {
      this.devToFlip = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(this.initialDev).length);
    }
    this.lastItem = this.devToFlip;
    $(this.initialDev).removeClass('animated flipInX');
    var randomInitial = $(this.initialDev).eq(this.devToFlip);
    randomInitial.addClass('animated flipInX');
    randomInitial.clone().appendTo("#loaded-devs").removeClass("initial animated flipInX");
  }
};

DevRotator.init();
```

```css
.animated {
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
<div class="loaded-dev featured-dev initial">
</div>
```